# How to do the 7 classes NER on Chinese with "Stanford Named Entity Recognizer" (not CoreNLP)

Tags: stanford-nlp

I found that I can do the 7 classes NER(wit date, money ...) on Chinese sentences with CoreNLP．
But I can only do the 4 classes NER　on Chinese sentences with　"Stanford Named Entity Recognizer"．
That is the case in offical　demo　website．

So how can I do the 7 classes NER on chinese sentences with "Stanford Named Entity Recognizer"?

Answer (score 0):

If you run this command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```

it will run 7-class NER tagging on Chinese text.

Comment: but it can't do the NER on customized segments, right?

Comment: what I really want is to do 7-class NER on customized chinese segments